# Why it's Shows Uncaught ReferenceError: setUserLoginDetails is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Showing Blank page with Undefine Error while using createSlice redux.
[Uncaught Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhco0.png)

**I tried following code**

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    photo: "",
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUserLoginDetails:(state,action)=>{
      state.name = action.payload.name;
      state.email = action.payload.email;
      state.photo = action.payload.photo;
    },
    setSignOutState: (state) =>{
        state.name = null;
        state.email = null;
        state.photo = null;
    },
  }
});

*export default {setUserLoginDetails,setSignOutState} = userSlice.actions*;//**I am getting error here that setUserLoginDetails is not define**

export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user.name;
export const selectUserEmail = (state) => state.user.email;
export const selectUserPhoto = (state) => state.user.photo;
```

I not getting what i am doing wrong

Comment: How are you importing `setUserLoginDetails`?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to export two variables that are not defined (setUserLoginDetails, setSignOutState).

Also, most likely you just want to export the variables (not them inside an object as default for the module).

Try this instead, declaring the variables with const:

```js
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    photo: "",
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUserLoginDetails:(state,action)=>{
      state.name = action.payload.name;
      state.email = action.payload.email;
      state.photo = action.payload.photo;
    },
    setSignOutState: (state) =>{
        state.name = null;
        state.email = null;
        state.photo = null;
    },
  }
});

export const {setUserLoginDetails,setSignOutState} = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user.name;
export const selectUserEmail = (state) => state.user.email;
export const selectUserPhoto = (state) => state.user.photo;

//also, you should export the reducer so you can register it in the store:
export default userSlice.reducer
```